# Netlify CMS build on themeforest theme

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms

I bought "SuperProps - React Next Landing Page Templates" from themeforest. This theme is based on the Gatsby-platform and this was hosted via Netlify.

I wish to implement Netlify CMS, so that, I can make changes on the site via CMS. Is there any way to implement CMS on our existing site developed on a theme.

Comment: Netlify CMS can definitely be connected to Gatsby and hosted on Netlify. It sounds like you're looking for a plug and play solution. Unfortunately, Gatsby will require a bit more wiring together than a plug and play solution offers.

I think you probably need to find a developer to help you connect It together then you will be off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

It can definitely be added to an existing site. Netlify CMS has installation instructions [here](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/gatsby/).

If you need help, I suggest you look at how a [template](https://github.com/robertcoopercode/gatsby-netlify-cms) implements this with Gatsby.

I also found some videos:

- [Netlify CMS Tutorial - Build a GatsbyJS Blog in 7 Minutes!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHWBPj-v028)
- [Get Started With Netlify CMS (with Benaiah Mischenko) — Learn With Jason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_QbyxeQrkk)
- [Deploy a Gatsby JS Site & Netlify CMS in just 45 mins! (2019 - Full Walkthrough)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjszBC8luHE)